# Is there a way to change the attribute that is called when generating package metadata (SafeConfigParser to RawConfigParser)?

Tags: python, metadata

```
xxx\versioneer.py", line 401, in get_config_from_root

parser = configparser.SafeConfigParser()

AttributeError: module 'configparser' has no attribute 'SafeConfigParser'. Did you mean: 'RawConfigParser'?
      [end of output]
```

note:

```
This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```